# Почему код с использованием opencv не компилируется, хотя библиотека собрана правильно?

Tags: c++, opencv, компиляция, библиотеки, сборка

Собрал opencv из исходников, следовал следующей инструкции

> http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/

После сборки совершил проверку командой `pkg-config --modversion opencv4`, версия успешно вывелась в терминал.
Я написал тестовый файл

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
 
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  
  cv::Mat image;
  image = cv::imread("sample.jpeg" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  
  if(! image.data ) {
      std::cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
      return -1;
    }
  
  cv::namedWindow( "Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow( "Display window", image );
  
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Я попробовал скомпилировать данный файл командой.

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Но компилятор выдал ошибку

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:7:38: error: ‘CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR’ was not declared in this scope
    7 |   image = cv::imread("sample.jpeg" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
      |                                      ^~~
```

Где я ошибся?

Comment: потому что в opencv4 нету такого дэфайна

Comment: Возможно, поможет замена CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR на cv::CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR или using namespace cv; в самом начале? Хотя, возможно, я написал глупость

Comment: При добавлении инклуда opencv.hpp не может найти core.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте

```
using namespace cv;
```